# Get CF7 input values to another form on another page

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to get the values of [this form](https://www.ryanpal.com/) diplayed on another form on [another page](https://www.ryanpal.com/sell-now/).

PS. The second form is not CF7. I believe Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension won't work.

I have already tried the following.

```
function save_cf7_data($cf)
{
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    // Get the post data and other post meta values.
    if ($submission) {
        session_start();
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        // Encode the data in a new array in JSON format
        $data = json_encode(array(
            "Property_Address" => "{$posted_data["Property_Address"]}",
            "Email" => "{$posted_data["Email"]}",
            "Phone" => "{$posted_data["Phone"]}",

        ));


        // Finally send the data to your custom endpoint
        $ch = curl_init(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/second-form.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); //Optional timeout value
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //Optional timeout value
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }
    }
    add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'save_cf7_data');
```

Question One:
How to pass the second form URL on `curl_init()`?

Question Two: 
How to get the variables on the second form php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save data in session:

on init hook you need start session if session not exist

```
add_action( 'init', 'mx_session_start' );
function 'mx_session_start'() {
    if ( empty( $_SESSION ) ) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

on you hook in example save data in session

```
$_SESSION['cf7'] = $data; //all your needed data.
```

Get your data in another form use $_SESSION['cf7']

or change cf7-form on simple form with action on your "another" page

Comment: Could you extend your answers please. I am not sure how to achieve either way.

Comment: Thanks, but still not clear. I have added your if statement to the top of the function. Added `$_SESSION['cf7'] = $data;` before the curl(). On the `second-form.php` i added on top `echo 'Form Data: ' .  $_SESSION['cf7'];`. Nothing echoes here.

Comment: You added session start on init hook?

Comment: What do you mean by 'init hook'?

Comment: Great. Thanks for the patience. I managed to make it work on my local env, but not on the live server. Could it be because of PHP version, live is at 5.6?

Comment: No....php 5.6+ good work with this code. Find your mistake in code

Comment: I have it working here http://149.28.13.162/~stefanomonteiro/ryanpal/

But not here https://www.ryanpal.com/

Same code, exported and imported the same way. Different server. What could cause this?